# How can I view the .edmx diagram on visual studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, database-design, schema

I want to view the edmx diagram like below 
[an example of how it is viewed on windows visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fty45.png)

I have tried looking at Microsofts documentations regarding this issue, but it still doesn't seem to work. I don't know how I can view this on visual studio for Mac. Instead, I get something like.

[this is the .edmx diagram file for the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IEaP.png)

Thank you!